# depthwise_Conv2D_native Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between the **[depthwise_conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d)** and **[depthwise_conv2d_native](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d_native)** in TensorFlow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the following unit test, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b0ecc7d2c1486367ec65d297e372f8935ee3ddfe/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/depthwise_conv_op_test.py#L87

.. they are indeed supposed to be identical (when no stride is present). `depthwise_conv2d_native` is the simpler implementation that doesn't have strides, and goes straight to a C++/CUDA operation. `depthwise_conv2d` takes an optional `stride` argument; it passes this into `with_space_as_batch` to do the stride, and then that calls `depthwise_conv2d_native` as the backend.

So, bottom line: there isn't a different in what they compute. In terms of performance, `depthwise_conv2d` could add marrrrrrginally more complexity to your model, but adds the flexibility that you can have variable strides.